# transfer fails with invalid output

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, synchronization, transfer

I'm using the latest `monero-wallet-cli` version `Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.0.2-release)` on linux. When I try to submit the transfer, it throws the following error:

`Error: transaction <txid> was rejected by daemon with status: Failed
Error: Reason: invalid output`

Additional Info:

- I'm using a remote node (moneroworld), I know, I know, but I don't have a SSD so monerod would take a looong time to sync
- I already recreated the wallet and refreshed it, to no avail
- I tried `rescan_bc` but it took a long time and finished after block 85000 or so

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Looks like rescan_bc wasn't finished. Try that again and wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using an old daemon, which cannot understand the new transaction output format. This is what you get for using some random daemon from somewhere on the internet :)

Either use your own, or find a sane one.